# Cypress unable to open X Display in WSL2

Tags: vue.js, cypress, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, xserver

I have followed every single step in this tutorial. Double Checked. Double Installed.

https://nickymeuleman.netlify.app/blog/gui-on-wsl2-cypress

But I get the error :

```
[3974:0912/194522.792278:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1402)] Unable to open X display.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
The Test Runner unexpectedly exited via a exit event with signal SIGABRT
```

Comment: Please, provide all the steps to reproduce the problem yourself, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question would become useless if a link were unavailable.

Comment: @james Did you fix this error? If so, can you please share how?

Comment: One thing to check is the value of your DISPLAY variable. The tutorial's method of setting this variable won't work if you've set up an external nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but there was a line before that same error message about Authentication. For me, I had to Disable Access Control after first ensuring all other running instances of VcXsrv were terminated:

[image: Disable access control]

Answer (score 1):

If you've configured an external nameserver, then following the steps of Nicky Meuleman's tutorial, the `DISPLAY` variable will be set wrong. The tutorial says to add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
```

... but if you've configured an external nameserver, `DISPLAY` will end up pointing to that server, and it won't work. Instead, you should do this:

```
export DISPLAY=$( cmd.exe /C netsh interface ip show addresses "vEthernet (WSL)" | grep "IP Address" | sed -e "s/\sIP Address:\s//g; s/\r//" ):0.0
```

This will set DISPLAY to (e.g.) `172.24.0.1:0.0` instead of `8.8.4.4:0.0`.